# Designing an Etched Border

Tags: java, swing, border

I want to design a GUI with theme of Black, but my etched border looks raised etched type.
I want to make it look lowered etched type. I can't find the color combination to do that. How would I do that?
It's looking like this, but the difference is that the background is Black.

[image: his image]

Comment: So you need a shadow & a highlight, unfortunately you used the darkest color you have for the background, which means any other color choice is probably going to make the border look raised. I might use dark grey & grey (from the java.awt.Color class)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a BevelBorder instead?

```
  JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
  outerPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
  outerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
  outerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
  Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED);
  Border innerPanelBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder , insideBorder );
  JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
  innerPanel.setBorder(innerPanelBorder);
  innerPanel.setOpaque(false);
  outerPanel.add(innerPanel);
```